# .NET Core Dependency Injection of static instance into generic concrete class to satisfy a generic class dependency

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, dependency-injection, static

Consider the following `AnimalContext<TAnimalType>` generic class that requires a factory of `IConfigurationFactory<TAnimalType>` in its constructor:

```
public class AnimalContext<TAnimalType> : IAnimalContext<TAnimalType> 
        where TAnimalType : AnimalDefinition
{
    private IConfigurationFactory<TAnimalType> factory;

    public AnimalType AnimalType { get; protected set; }

    public AnimalContext(IConfigurationFactory<TAnimalType> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;

        AnimalType = GetAnimalType();
    }
}
```

To build the dependency we have another class `ConfigurationFactory<TConfigurationType>` and this class in turn depends on an instance of `IFactory`:

```
public class ConfigurationFactory<TConfigurationType> : IConfigurationFactory<TConfigurationType> 
        where TConfigurationType : class
{
    private IFactory factory;

    public ConfigurationFactory(IFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
}
```

`IFactory` however does not have concrete implementations but rather an abstract class that inherits from `IFactory`, namely `BaseFactory`.

```
public abstract class BaseFactory : IFactory
{
    protected BaseFactory()
    {
    }

    private Type animalType;

    protected Type AnimalType
    {
        get { return this.animalType; }
        set { this.animalType = value; }
    }
}
```

Finally, we have a cat factory that is a sealed class with a static member `CatFactory`. As you can imagine we can create a `DogFactory`, `BearFactory` etc.

```
public sealed class CatFactory : BaseFactory
{
    private static CatFactory instance = new CatFactory();

    private CatFactory()
    {
        this.AnimalType = typeof(Cat);
    }

    public static CatFactory Instance
    {
        get { return CatFactory.instance; }
    }
}
```

The question here is how one registers `IConfigurationFactory<TAnimalType>` in the startup class so that the right factory gets created using dependency injection. This is some old code I'm porting to .NET Core 5.0 and it uses AutoFAC DI. I would like to use .NET Core's own DI.

Clearly the issue is we somehow have to create a very specific factory dependent on the type but this class is an instance. Only one exists.  How do we do this? AutoFAC seemed to be able to handle it with something like the snippet below.

```
private static void SetupPageContextAndFactory<TAnimalType, TConfigurationFactory, TAnimalContext>( ContainerBuilder builder, AnimalType animalType, IFactory factory )
{
     app.RegisterType<TConfigurationFactory>()
    .WithParameter(
        (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(IFactory),
        (p, c) => factory
        )
        .WithParameter(
        (p, c) => p.ParameterType == typeof(AnimalType),
        (p, c) => animalType
        )
    .As<IConfigurationFactory<TAnimalType>>()
    .Keyed<IAnimalFactory>(animalType)
    .InstancePerRequest();
}
```

Comment: Please show the configuration you are currently using to achieve this with Autofac.

Comment: @Steven  I edited the question and added a snippet of how it was done using autoFAC  That was .Net standard

Comment: IMHO add `IFactory<T> : IFactory`, then register `.AddSingleton<IFactory<Cat>>(p => CatFactory.Instance)`. Though I would also recommend you remove those static instances.

Comment: And probably change `BaseFactory<T>` as well.

Comment: You can try the following code: `services.AddTransient<IConfigurationFactory<TAnimalType>>(p => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TConfigurationFactory>(p, factory, animalType));`. You only have to think of a way of replacing `Keyed<T>`, because that's not something that MS.DI supports.